# Find the distribution: multivariate normals

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $x_0$ and $x$ be random vectors with the same distribution $N_p(0,I)$, where $x_0$ and $x$ are independent. Can I find the distribution of $\frac{x_0^T x}{|x_0|}?$

I know that the distribution of $x_0^T x_0$ and $x^Tx$ is $\chi_{(p)}^2$ because these are sums of squared standard normals. But in the case of $x_0^T x$ this is a sum of products of different normals. I don't know if maybe the denominator does the trick and simplify some things. Any hints?

Comment: Write it as $\sum x_{0i}x_i/\sqrt{\sum x_{0i}^2}$ and condition on $x_{0i}$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom can you please give me some insights on your comment? why the condition on $x_{0i}$ would help me in order to find the required distribution? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $x_0=(x_{01},x_{02},\ldots,x_{0p})^T$ and $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_p)^T$, so that  the $x_{0i}$'s and $x_i$'s are both i.i.d standard normal. So if you condition on the $x_{0i}$'s, say $x_{0i}=a_i$ for every $i$, then the conditional distribution of $\frac{x_0^T x}{\lVert x_0\rVert}$ is exactly standard normal:

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^p a_ix_i}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^p a_i^2}}\sim N(0,1)$$

As the conditional distribution does not depend on the $a_i$'s, the (unconditional) distribution of  $\frac{x_0^T x}{\lVert x_0\rVert}$ is independent of $x_0$. Hence the unconditional distribution is same as the conditional distribution, given by

$$\frac{x_0^T x}{\lVert x_0\rVert}\sim N(0,1)$$

Comment: Thank you very much